# How can I make this for loop iteration available inside the function for the if( condition ) with out repeating the function outcome n times as i?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function which requires an Array iteration in order to set proper conditionals in the if statement, here's the code:

```
const code = reactive([] as string[])
    for (let field = 0; field < props.length; field++) code.push('')

    const inputs = reactive([] as HTMLInputElement[])
    const focusOn = ref(0 as number | null)

    onMounted(() => {
      inputs[0].focus()
    })


    const nextInput = (): void => {
      for (let i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        console.log(code[i])
        console.log(code)
        if (
          focusOn.value !== null &&
          focusOn.value < props.length - 1 &&
          code[i] !== ' ' &&
          code[i] !== undefined
        ) {
          inputs[focusOn.value + 1].focus()
        }
      }
    }
```

You can ignore the console.log.

> **the problem I'm having is that the outcome ⇒ inputs[i + 1] is not
> working as expected ⇒ stepping to the next input by 1, instead is
> doing something like inputs[i +1] * 4 in every click** ⇒ I assume it's
> the number of iterations which by the way is 4, that's the
> code.length.

`focusOn.value ⇒ index number`

What I'm trying to achieve is to iterate the code object[] in order to use its outcome as conditionals, but not to have it in the same scope as the **return**, so I can avoid returning the result x times as iterations.

I already tried numerous things, but I'm having an understanding level problem here. How can I solve this? Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

btw, I just added more code to give you context that was clearly missing, my bad.

Comment: What is `code`? What is `focusOn`? What is `inputs`? People can't help if it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: I made it longer, with images and code but was too extensive, thus, no response. However is true, I will add the things u said, thank u!

Comment: Your code is still not totally clear but your previous question was a bit more helpful in at least explaining what you're trying to do. I think you've overcomplicated the problem. The approach shown in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-spence-q7tk0g?file=/src/App.vue) is much simpler and I think accomplishes what you want using even listeners, native event properties/functions, and v-model